# Extract Values from XML Name/Value schema and show as columns in result

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery, sql-server-2012

Given that I have information stored like this in an XML column with a schema like the one below -

```
<root>
  <Setting>
     <Name>BookingDate</Name>
     <Value>01 Jan 2013</Value>
  </Setting>
  <Setting>
     <Name>Price</Name>
     <Value>23.66</Value>
  </Setting>
</root>
```

Can I write a query that will extract the 'Name' as a column and the 'Setting' as the row value so they appear as if I have done a simple select on that row i.e.

```
RowID | NormalColumn1 | NormalColumn2 | BookingDate  | Price
-------------------------------------------------------------
 1    |   X           |   Y           | 01 Jan 2013  | 23.66
```

I can do a static query but how can I write one that would return more results as items are added to the XML? I would like to put this in a view with a Select * so as people add more information to the XML more results will show up from the query on the view.

I could then index this schema and maybe even get to the point where the  is typed. The purpose is to store information that is not yet known about.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does the XML look like when there is more than one row? Where do X and Y come from? It looks like there is other important information missing from your question.

Comment: the normalcolumn results from from the table which holds the XML. I was trying to show that I want the results from the XML query to show up as normal results do. Every <Setting> node needs to look like a new column in the result set. It also needs to be dynamic so as new items are added to the XML the number of columns in the results grow with it. Does this help?

Comment: Does the data have to be stored as XML? Why can't true tables be created that get columns added to them? One problem with what you're asking for is that there is no guarantee, from row to row, that the "columns" in the XML data will be consistently the same. So you have to do some global meta-analysis first, to determine all the possible columns, in order to address each of them properly. This is a challenging problem.

Comment: We have a number of clients all running their own version of the database. If they are all allowed to add columns to the database schema it will turn into an un-maintainable mess. It sure is a challenging problem, hence why I haven't solved it already :-).

Comment: Please tag when responding (as in @Erik). It is pure chance I saw your comment.

Comment: Are you prepared to have the awful performance of reading every row in the table prior to returning the filtered result set? Do you have  no metadata anywhere about what pseudo-columns to expect?

Comment: @Erik sorry, yes, there will be table that holds the information about what fields ('Name' nodes) will be in the XML. If a user adds a new field type it will go into this table, and then upon adding new rows the xml will be checked to make sure nothing is getting saved that hasnt already been added. Does that help at all? I have already got the point of writing a stored procedure that builds a dynamic sql statement which returns what I want, the problem is I can't use this in a view and it sounds like even if I did get it into a view it wouldnt update itself like I need it too.

Comment: That is kind of crucial information to have left out of your question. The time I spent yesterday figuring out how to get the list of pseudocolumns could have been spent giving you an answer instead. I'll try to get back to this in some hours--I can't spend more time right now.

Comment: In fact I see that someone else has answered with pretty much exactly what I was going to say. So never mind. Build the view from a trigger on your metadata table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the query dynamically to have a dynamic number of columns and to figure out what columns that is you need to parse ever node of the XML and that can be hard on the server if there are a fair amount of rows in the table.

I suggest that you have a table `Setting` that holds the valid settings name and that you update that table in a trigger to the `Settings` table.

To have a view that reflects the settings you have you can add a trigger on the table `Setting` that dynamically updates the view.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/184b3/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Settings
(
  RowID int identity primary key,
  Settings xml
) 

go

create table Setting
(
  Name varchar(20) primary key
)

go

create view v_Settings as 
select RowID 
from Settings

go

create trigger tr_Settings on Settings for insert, update as
with C(Name) as
(
  select distinct T.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') 
  from inserted as I
    cross apply I.Settings.nodes('/root/Setting/Name') as T(N)
)
insert into Setting(Name)
select Name
from C
where C.Name not in (select Name from Setting) 

go

create trigger tr_Setting on Setting for insert as
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = 'alter view v_Settings as ' + 
           'select S.RowID'+
           (
           select ',S.Settings.value(''(root/Setting[Name="' + 
                  S.Name + 
                  '"]/Value/text())[1]'', ''varchar(max)'') as '+
                  quotename(S.Name)
           from Setting as S
           for xml path(''), type
           ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')+
           ' from Settings as S'

exec (@SQL)
```

**Query 1**:

```
insert into Settings values
('<root>
  <Setting>
     <Name>BookingDate</Name>
     <Value>01 Jan 2013</Value>
  </Setting>
  <Setting>
     <Name>Price</Name>
     <Value>23.66</Value>
  </Setting>
</root>')

select *
from v_Settings
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/184b3/3/1)**:

```
| ROWID | BOOKINGDATE | PRICE |
-------------------------------
|     5 | 01 Jan 2013 | 23.66 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
insert into Settings values
('<root>
  <Setting>
     <Name>BookingDate</Name>
     <Value>02 Jan 2013</Value>
  </Setting>
  <Setting>
     <Name>PriceX</Name>
     <Value>24.66</Value>
  </Setting>
</root>')

select *
from v_Settings
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/184b3/3/3)**:

```
| ROWID | BOOKINGDATE |  PRICE | PRICEX |
-----------------------------------------
|     5 | 01 Jan 2013 |  23.66 | (null) |
|     6 | 02 Jan 2013 | (null) |  24.66 |
```

**Update:**

From a comment above it looks like you already have a table that keeps track of all possible setting names. If that is the case you don't need the trigger on `Settings`. 
You actually don't need the trigger on `Setting` either if you just make sure that the view is rebuilt after you have updated the table `Setting`.

Comment: I think the trigger is a good idea though, I can just set it on the Meta Table.